# How to get the source of the click event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

With jQuery, I'm generating some buttons inside one div.

One button looks like the following:

```
<button type="button" value="A_DIFFERENT_VALUE_EACH_TIME" class="col-md-4 text-center btn btn-default btn-lg" >
  <h3>A_DIFFERENT_TEXT_EACH_TIME</h3>
</button>
```

I've like 10 of those, in one single div. What I need is one event handler that give me the `value` of the clicked button.

So far I've done the following:

```
$("#card-subcontainer button").click(function(event){handleCardChoosed(event.target);})
```

but it doesn't work, because `event.target`may be the `h3` or the `button`. How can I get always the element on which we registered the click event(and not like currently the one who did get the focus?

Comment: Use `this` instead

Comment: When binding `$("#card-subcontainer button")` then `this` should be a reference to the currently clicked button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binding is on the buttons `$("#card-subcontainer button")` hence the `this` context should be a reference to the clicked button.

```js
$("#card-subcontainer button").click(function() {
  console.log(this); // this is the reference to the clicked button element
  console.log(this.value); // use this to access the value of the button
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="card-subcontainer">
  <button type="button" value="1" class="col-md-4 text-center btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <h3>1st</h3>
  </button>
  <button type="button" value="2" class="col-md-4 text-center btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <h3>2nd</h3>
  </button>
  <button type="button" value="3" class="col-md-4 text-center btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <h3>3rd</h3>
  </button>
  <button type="button" value="4" class="col-md-4 text-center btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <h3>4th</h3>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking that `this` would be the refering the `this` that registered the event(`window`) in this case, my bad! I think it work. Just a question, I had to drop the `button` element to use another kind of html element. is there a way to retrieve a custom "value" attribute of a div? I tried the "attr('value')", but I get some errors

Comment: never mind, I was having my custom tag on the parent container. Sorry about that

Comment: `is there a way to retrieve a custom "value" attribute of a div?` - If it is a data attribute, e.g.: `data-value="5"` you can use `$('div').data('value')` to retrieve it and if it is totally custom e.g: `myCustomAtt="Foo"` then you can use `$('div').attr('myCustomAtt')` to get the value